# Azure Devops API - Can't find a way to get permission groups/membership using API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am looking for a way to use the Azure DevOps API to get membership of permission groups.  The data I am looking for is in the following location on the front end:

[image]

I had the same requirement to get team membership within Azure DevOps and was able to do so using the following URI:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/hrs/teams/{teamname}/members?api-version=6.0`

I could not find a similar URI to get permission groups and need a way to pull this information using the API.

I've tried many of the API endpoints on the official api documentation (below) focusing on any that seem like they may pull security group related information.   In all cases I came up short either because the endpoint did not provide me with what I was looking for, or the documentation for an endpoint wasn't clear on how parameters need to be structured for more advanced use cases.

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP`

I also tried asking this question to ChatGPT however the endpoints the chatbot provided me with did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get what I am looking for, but I am not a big fan of the approach.

You can use the [graph API to list all permission groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

once you have the permission groups, you can write a script to filter for the group object within the API response you want to get the members of.

The group object has the appropriate API endpoint to hit to get the member objects within the `_links.memberships` property.

Call the API with the memberships link from above.  It will return an array of descriptors which can be used in further API calls.

For each descriptor, hit the appropriate API endpoint to resolve the object for that descriptor.  If the descriptor starts with `aad` then it is a user and you can use the [user get api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP).  If the descriptor starts with `aadgp` then it is a group and you use the [group get api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP).

This strategy is rather complicated and requires an API call for each member of the group.  I'd hope there is a better solution.

Also worth noting is that the above strategy will get all permission groups as well as teams within azure devops.  The returned objects don't include anything that allows you to distinguish a group from a team as they are both vssgp objects.

The best way I found to get only the permission groups is to use the above approach, then also make a call to `https://{org}.visualstudio.com/_apis/projects/{project}/teams` then compare then get a list of all of the `name` properties for the objects in this call and filter those out by comparing them to the `displayname` property in the graph api call above.  If you have multiple projects, then you will need to repeat this process for each project.